# Can 'classical' be used only for sophisticated cultures?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I have read some arcicles about the difference between 'classic' and 'classical'. I understand that 'classical' things are much older than 'classic' things, and relate to qualified cultures.

To make the understanding clearer, I'd like to know whether 'classical' can be used only for sophisticated traditional cultures such as music, literature, art and scientific and philosophical theories (e.g. classical physics, classical economics).

Is there any example of more ordinary thing which can be classical?

Comment: That's right. However, *classic* is not the same thing: a classic joke, a classic attitude etc.

Comment: [A good dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/classical) should explain when *classical* is commonly used (and when *classic* is used), although it won't cover every case. Classical things are generally older than their opposites, but there isn't a fixed cut-off ([classical genetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_genetics) is a scientific approach opposed to molecular genetics, and contemporary classical music is inspired by old things rather than being old-  but isn't popular music). What specific answer are you looking for? What do you mean "more ordinary thing"?

Comment: [Classical music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_period_(music)) is the musical side of a broader movement in the arts in Europe: [Classicism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classicism). Classical art drew on some aspects of the art of Ancient Greece and Rome. In particular, classical music is characterised by simple textures of melody and accompaniment. It is not classical by virtue of being old. "Classical music" in the over-extended sense of "not any of the pop or folk genres" is better termed "art music".

Comment: 'Classical' is ill-defined (perhaps disambiguated by capitalisation) in the music domain. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_period_(music)): 'The Classical period was an era of classical music between roughly 1730 and 1820. The Classical period falls between the Baroque and the Romantic periods.'

Comment: I would go so far as to say that "classical," "Classical," and "classic" are so frequently abused and interchanged (not to mention fraught with problematic ideologies) that I would avoid them in general and prefer more direct descriptions.

Comment: @StuartF By "ordinary", I meant things which are enjoyed not only by highly educated people, but also by ordinary people (though people cannot be classified clearly in this day an age). For example, in Japan, some people use 'classical' to describe retro-style motorcycles and cars, but I think it is an incorrect usage of the word. Native speakers only say 'classic motorcycles (cars)'. I wanted to confirm whether or not 'classical' relates only to traditional humanities, arts and sciences (so-called [high culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_culture)).

Comment: In order for the adjective *classical* to have meaning, it has to be applied to things that are already established, usually with the intent of contrasting them to things that are *modern*, or at least different, as in *classical mechanics* versus *quantum mechanics*, or *early music* versus *classical music*. In order for something to attain the status of *classical*, it’s going to need some time to settle into a pattern that people can agree on. However, one could reasonably speak of *classical skateboarding* as opposed to longboarding, e-boarding or other forms.